# Show hidden div when certain value is selected

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have dynamic fields generated through jquery. I am able to display these fields through a select function trigger `.change`. Every select field has three options `Biology`, `Calculus` and `Others-Not listed`. When choosing `Others-not listed` with value of `3`, the function displays a hidden div. My problem is that if there are two select fields and one has option `Others-not listed` chosen it will show the hidden div for all other select. I would like to just show this hidden div for the particular select field. [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/QUKwL/13/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('select').change(function() {
        var option = $(this).val();
        showFields(option);
        return false;
    });
    function showFields(option){ 

        var content = '';
        for (var i = 1; i <= option; i++){
            content += '<div id="course_' + i + '"><label>Course # ' + i + '</label><br /><label>Course Name:</label> <select id="coursename_' + i + '" name="coursename_' + i + '" class="ddlcss"><option value="">--- Select ---</option>"'
            content += '<option value="1">Biology</option>'; content += '<option value="2">Calculus</option>'; content += '<option value="3">Other - Not Listed</option>'; '"';

            content += '</select><div class="hideNewCourse" style="display:none;"><label for="newCourse_'+i+'">Add Course Name to List:</label><input type="text" id="newCourse_'+i+'" name="newCourse_'+i+'"/></div></br></div>';

            $(document).on('change',"#coursename_"+i, function(){
                if ($(this).val() == "3"){
                    $(".hideNewCourse").show();    
                }else{
                    $(".hideNewCourse").hide();
                }
            });

        }
        $('#course_catalog').html(content);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are anyways delegating the events. Instead of binding the event to each element specifically just use **[Attribute starts with](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/)** selector.

```
$(document).on('change',"#coursename_"+i, function(){
```

can be changed to

```
$(document).on('change',"[id^=coursename_]", function() {
```

**And move it out of the showFields method**

And to show and hide the specific element containing to the container, use a mix of closest , which gets to the parent and then find the `hideContainer` div for that corresponding block.

```
$(".hideNewCourse").show();
```

will then change to

```
$(this).closest('div').find(".hideNewCourse")
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QUKwL/16/)**

Comment: This is helpful as well. I read more about it. Will use this.

Comment: You went beyond my request. Thank you.

Comment: @techAddict82.. Glad to have helped :)

Answer (score 2):

Change your code for the select fields to:

```
if ($(this).val() == "3") {
    $(this).parent().find(".hideNewCourse").show();
} else {
    $(this).parent().find(".hideNewCourse").hide();
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/QUKwL/14/)**

In your code, `$(".hideNewCourse")` will show or hide all the elements with that class. By using `$(this).parent().find(".hideNewCourse")` you only select the element relative to the select that was changed.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".hideNewCourse").show();
```

The above represents all the elements with this class.

You have to be selective like

```
$(this).parent().find(".hideNewCourse").show();
```

Then,

```
$(document).on('change',"#coursename_"+i, function(){
                if ($(this).val() == "3"){
                    $(this).parent().find(".hideNewCourse").show();    
                }else{
                    $(this).parent().find(".hideNewCourse").hide();
                }
            });
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/QUKwL/15/)

Answer (score 0):

Try using the [`.next()`](http://api.jquery.com/next/) function so it only grabs the next object, instead of all of them:

So instead of this:

```
    $(".hideNewCourse").show();
```

Do this:

```
     $(this).next(".hideNewCourse").show();
```

And you would do the same for hide:

```
     $(this).next(".hideNewCourse").hide();
```